# help with correct components for Fluid dynamic experiment and the circuitry on board testing rocket

Tags: components

I have a project that I am attempting to build and I know generically what I need to order but the detail is the problem.I have tried trawling though catalogs to find the appropriate component sensors and the connection cabling between them but have been unable to come up with the specs I need to run my experiment. I have drawn my project schematic if needed to help explain my problem.
I am not an engineer so please excuse my attempt to ask the right questions or even the way I have asked the questions. I need the following;

1. Accelerometer +/- 50 g and analog type as I need continuous data not digital with PWM, and it must have a resolution of 10^-4 to 10^-6g
2. Data acquisition device (data logger) ....not sure if this would be a microcontroller, i.e. an arduino compatible using the ATmega32BP,
3. Do I need a signal conditioner if I purchase a data logger that perhaps already conditions the signal trace ?i.e. I think engineers either shift the level (voltage input up or down and also cut out the background noise of the signal)
4. A fluid static pressure sensor (i.e. a pressure transducer),
5. A small/compact size electrometer sensor to measure current (I) OR voltage,
6. The cabling that connects all of these devices.....not sure if RS232 or usb etc
7. I will use a microfluidic peristaltic pump (IPC-N) and it will have a RS232 so I need compatibility with the components above. Maybe I need to find some sort of adapter/s to connect up all the component sensors

Any help would be appreciated so I can order what I need or perhaps I have not identified something else that I also need? On board power supply will not be a problem as this has already been worked out.

Comment: I have a wheel, another wheel, some metal bars and a chain. Can I make a bicycle? There are 1000's of wheels, so I don't know. There are 10000's of "sensors". You're not seriously expecting us to read all the datasheets in the world?

Comment: "is this actually able to function as a Data acquisition device for the above 4 devices?" Hmm, yes it is ! Or not ? Hmmm, well maybe. Why don't you try and let us know :-)

Answer (score 2):

Generally the Arduino will accept an analog voltage between 0V and the supply voltage on the analog inputs (some Arduinos are 5V, some are 3.3V).

The built-in ADC has a resolution of 10 bits (0..1023). You can find more specs in the appropriate Atmel datasheet for the CPU, but generally you won't want to exceed 10K source impedance.

So whatever sensor you want to measure, you will probably want to convert the useful range into the same range (or a bit less) as the ATMega ADC accepts. That will maximize the resolution. If the sensor voltage is higher, you can use a voltage divider, provided the source impedance is not too high. If the sensor voltage is lower you can make an amplifier. If it needs to be shifted in level (for example from -5 ~ +5V to 0~5V) you can make a level shifter/amplifier or level shifter/attenuator.

One thing to keep in mind is that the reference for the ADC is the supply voltage, so it will only be as good as the regulator (and likely a bit worse than that). You can reasonably expect 0.1% resolution but only a few percent accuracy.

If your project requires a higher accuracy than the built-in ADC can provide, you can add an external ADC (for example, a 24-bit delta-sigma converter) with a proper reference. Getting much better than about 16 bits real accuracy can be challenging, however.. and 20 bits of real accuracy (+/-1ppm) is often as good as we can do without spending a fortune.

Other factors to consider beyond signal conditioning are how fast you need to be able to measure (and process) the data, and whether you require an anti-aliasing filter ahead of the ADC to prevent high frequency signals from aliasing down to your signal band.

Welcome to Electronics.SE and when you get further along in your project and have specific questions I am sure that we shall be able to help.

Comment: Spehro thanks for the helpful comments. I dont have any of the four sensor components I mentioned yet so my question was more general in terms of capability of the XC4210 arduino compatible. I am not an engineer so all the jargon takes a while to decipher. I believe the XC4210 has 32kb of available memory and I feeling this may be inadequate to record sensor information in milli or even micro second time intervals from "four types of sensors". My project will only run for 2 seconds. Any further comment would be appreciated.